# Unable to connect to my android device via ADB

Tags: android

Sorry for the nooby question, I am having trouble sorting this out using the web.

I am trying to simply connect my device to my pc via adb to debug my application.

My device is rooted. Adb debugging is enabled. I downloaded an adb running application and started ADB.

Now i am trying adb connect ip:5555. and keep on getting "unable to connect to ip:5555" ...

Same happend when i try to connect via usb.

```
c:\>adb connect 192.168.20.191:5555
unable to connect to 192.168.20.191:5555
```

Help...?

EDIT: 
C:>adb devices
List of devices attached 
06fecaa1    unauthorized

Comment: how do you know that `192.168.20.191:5555` is correct? use `adb devices` to check if your device is detected.

Comment: You wrote `adb connect` twice in a row. That's not the problem, I know, but still.

Comment: "I downloaded an adb running application..." you need to download the official Android SDK which contains ADB

Comment: Edited please look, the ip is the ip of my phone.

Comment: If 06fecaa1 is unauthorized, you should revoke permissions in Developer Mode and then reconnect...this time your device should ask for permissions which you should grant, either one-time or always.

Answer (score 9):

## Launching Cordova

1. Open Node.js / CMD
2. Point to "the directory where you have located your source folder" >>> C:\Projects\RJX
3. Enable Wifi
4. Turn on Developer Option under settings
5. Enable / Check USB Debugging Option under settings (Google if cannot find this option)
6. Enable / Check the MTP Option under settings (Google if cannot find this option)

### ADB Commands

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
//plug off cable from mobile and plug in again if you connected your device earlier
//Uninstall the application from mobile if you already installed. (if necessary)
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect "ip" //adb connect 192.192.2.128
adb devices //to check device details
cordova run android --device
```

if this steps are not worked, try to close the cmd and do it again. Sometimes it needs some refresh.
**Android devices version 4.0.4 and after should be no problem if you follow these steps.

Comment: what this question has to do with cordova?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are able to understand adb connect / ip's etc I won't bore you with that

but there are two lame "gotcha's"

**THE GENYMOTION GOTCHA**

genymotion WRECKS a lot of this sometimes.. I am sorry but it does.. it has a "I know what I am doing I am taking over" mentality.. sadly it doesn't know what it's doing :-P  often you have to turn off genymotion for the adb->usb to work.. basically connect phone FIRST ... make sure it's there in eclipse (adb kill-server / start server if needs be ), then AND ONLY THEN then genymotion AFTER

**THE OOPS [/facepalm] GOTCHA**

check that your phone it isn't in Windows merely as a "Camera" - go to My Computer and look. If it looks like this pic it's that you're **not** running `Samsung Kies`(/disabled because it's annoying) the phone still goes "blub bling" when you plug it in, it may be connected via wifi so have a LAN ip but it is NOT really "connected" to ur PC. [image] **instead run/download/update this** (with phone disconnected) then make sure Kies is happy **AND MAKE SURE**  [MTU is enabled](http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Samsung-Galaxy-S3.how_to_change_the_usb_connection_options_on_my)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when PC was (accidentally) NOT in the same network as Android. When I logged on Android to the same WIFI network as PC it now works perfect and I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is that it's not listening on the correct (default) port. So you need to set the TCP/IP port to 5555. Connect your device via USB and issue the following command in cmd (terminal):

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Following this your adb connect should work fine, e.g.:

```
adb connect 192.168.0.n
```

Hope this fixes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I was previously connected with one device (e.g. `apps2fire`) and then tried using `adb` command from another machine.  I rebooted the Android device and then tried again and received the prompt to allow the connection as I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your ip address in your device, then following this command.

1. `adb kill-server`
2. `adb tcpip 5555`
3. `adb connect [your-ip-address]:5555`