# Unable to connect android device over adb TCP/IP

Tags: android, tcp, adb

I'm trying to debug on an android device over wlan using adb. I'm using ubuntu and the newest version of adb. And android version is over 4.x  But I fail to connect it.I tried

```
     ~$ adb connect 10.147.102.16
     unable to connect to 10.147.102.16:5555

    ~$ adb tcpip 5555
    error: device not found

    ~$ adb kill-server
    ~$ adb tcpip 5555
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
    * daemon started successfully *
    error: device not found

    ~$ adb connect 10.147.102.16
```

However, I'm able to ping it.

```
    ~$ ping 10.147.102.16
    PING 10.147.102.16 (10.147.102.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.147.102.16: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=683 ms
    64 bytes from 10.147.102.16: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=508 ms
    64 bytes from 10.147.102.16: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=339 ms
    64 bytes from 10.147.102.16: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=467 ms
    64 bytes from 10.147.102.16: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=82.4 ms
    ^C
    --- 10.147.102.16 ping statistics ---
    5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4000ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 82.452/416.321/683.404/199.953 ms
```

I have found some possible solutions on google, however all of them are for android phone devices and requires using the shell on the phone or modifying some files on the devices. I'm now using a television Top Box with android system. And it is not possible for me to do anything like that. Can anyone help me?

Something more, I use my own android phone as a test. The first time I use `adb connect` , I succeed in connecting to the phone and debug the program on it. However, after rebooting the phone, I found it impossible to connect to it again. So what's the problem of this...

=======================================

Already solved. Was specific device-related issue. Same process should work for an Android phone.

Comment: On a secured device, you must have a working ADB-over-USB connection to set ADB-over-TCP mode, and your error responses seem to indicate that you do not.  So focus first on getting ADB working via USB.  But your set top box may also behave differently - do you know that ADB is even enabled on it?

Comment: yeah, I'm working for a project on the set top box and the staff in that company use adb like this. So I'm quite sure it should work. Howerver, I'm not able to get immediate answer from them now, so I come here hoping to find any tips. And it does not seem to support debuging via USB……

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to my android device via ADB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076992/unable-to-connect-to-my-android-device-via-adb)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. And I answered it there http://stackoverflow.com/a/38717904/2401535.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch This was a different problem. I was pretty sure they were under the same network. The issue might be some security configs on the device as the same thing works for an Android phone in my case.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with my motorola moto x device.

The solution is you need to set the TCP/IP port to 5555.
Connect your device via USB and issue the command

```
$ adb tcpip 5555
```

After that remove the USB and connect the device to wifi

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb connect 192.168.45.42 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.45.42:5555
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This question was post months ago and your solution do work for android mobiles. For my case, it was related to the security design of the set top box. I eventually solved it by using a serial port communication.

Comment: nope, still not working for me    ./adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/xx
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
unable to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/xx:5555

Comment: After 30s it gives me "unable to connect to 10.0.2.15:5555: Operation timed out". MacOs, Android Emulator API 23

Answer (score 1):

*You need to kill the adb server then restart it*

I spent a day or so... finally saw a thread somewhere that said the above and it worked first time...after killing and starting:  Hope that helps
I had never used adb b4 doing this so I thing the server never started

To get adb.exe to talk with tablet:

1) Start AdbWireless on rooted tablet, it will tell you what to type in
2) Go to adb.exe location in WindowsExplorer, hold shift key down and right click in open part of WindowsExplorer window and select open command window.
3) Type in: adb kill-server
       adb start-server
       connect 192.168.1.294   (whatever your tablets ip address is)

should say connected...type: adb devices to see your tablet